# If statement skipped in django view for authenticated user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Good evening,

I have a view that works only if im logged as superuser, but not as "departmentsupervisor"

```
def detail_employee(request, pk, employee_pk):
    department = get_object_or_404(Department, pk=pk)
    print(department.supervisor, request.user.username)
    if request.user.username == department.supervisor or request.user.is_superuser:
        employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, department__pk=pk, pk=employee_pk)
        review = get_object_or_404(Result, pk=pk)
        print(employee, review.id)
        return render(request, 'review_employee.html', {'employee': employee})
return redirect('dept_employees', pk=department.pk)
```

Im validating with the print that user logged is == department.supervisor but the if statement is skipped, if im logged with superuser it works properly.

Im trying to look what I did wrong here.

Thanks

Edit adding models.

```
    class Department(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=75, unique=True)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        supervisor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='supervisor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: are `department.supervisor` and `request.user.username` are of same data type ?

Comment: department.supervisor comes from a model
supervisor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='supervisor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Can you add your `models.py`  too

Comment: Added the departmen model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `if` condition as follows,/

```
if request.user == department.supervisor or request.user.is_superuser:
```

`request.user.username` is a `str` type where as `department.supervisour` is a `User` class object

Comment: Thank you! now everything looks fine